# How to stretch tiles for certain zoom levels in custom ImageMapType implementation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've implemented a custom [ImageMapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ImageMapType) that returns valid tile URLs based on the given coordinates and zoom level of getTileUrl().

```
new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    name: 'Satellite',
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        var p_type = "satellite",
            z = zoom - 11,
            corr = Math.pow(2, zoom) - Math.pow(2, z),
            p_x = coord.x - corr,
            p_y = coord.y - corr,
            maxCoord = Math.pow(2, (z+1)) - 1;

        if (p_x > maxCoord || p_y > maxCoord || p_x < 0 || p_y < 0) {
            return 'http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/transparent.png';
        }

        p_x = (p_x < 16 ? '0' : '') + p_x.toString(16);
        p_y = (p_y < 16 ? '0' : '') + p_y.toString(16);

        return 'http://map.example.com/' + p_type + '/' + (z + 1) + '/tile_' + p_y + p_x + '.jpg';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(128, 128),
    isPng: false,
    minZoom: 11,
    maxZoom: 16
});
```

I have 128x128 tiles for zoom level 11 to 16. By increasing the maxZoom property of the ImageMapTypeOptions object to more than 16 it is possible to zoom beyond where there are tiles (but no tiles will appear of course, but markers and polylines does work). In this case I would like to have the tiles stretched from the previous zoom layer (in the same way as the transition effect when changing zoom level).

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. That should theoretically be possible to do on the client, but as the `getTileUrl` method of 
`google.maps.ImageMapType` object must return URL, you must do it on the server when you use this object.

Another possiblity would be to use more general [`google.maps.MapType`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapType) object instead and define your own `getTile` method. Then you could possibly return your own stretched `<img>` element.

Comment: Part one of TMS's answer was my thought exactly. Ran into something similar, and by generating the image + URL somewhere different (in my case: a REST api) and applying my logic there fixed it for me. Unfortunately the `getTileUrl` method doesn't have very much room to play with and accepts only URL's.